# Checkout.com payment integration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkout-payments

I am using checkout.com payment gateway. I want to integrate it to my website but in their developer area I am not able to find any suitable solution to integrate it with codeigniter. Below is the developer area of checkout.com

http://developers.checkout.com/

Any help in this regard will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: what you want in checkout

Comment: If you are familiar with composer that would be way to go. If not, google/search stack overflow for "codeigniter+composer" solutions. Btw, at the [end of the page](https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library#sample-code-for) you have code samples

Comment: I am familiar with composer. But what will be the use of composer in that case?

Answer (score 0):

They are providing this code for implementation :

window.CKOConfig = {
        debugMode: true,
        publicKey: 'Your public key',
        customerEmail: 'user@email.com',
        ready: function (event) {
            console.log("CheckoutKit.js is ready");
            CheckoutKit.monitorForm('.card-form', CheckoutKit.CardFormModes.CARD_TOKENISATION);
        },
        apiError: function (event) {
            // ...
        }

But I am not able to understand that how I will call it with dynamic data and with my some conditions?

Answer (score 0):

They won't give you a codeigniter integration, you can do it yourself with plain PHP though:

https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library

Did you even read [their documentation](http://developers.checkout.com/docs/server/api-reference/overview)?

Comment: Thank you Gustavo. I already downloaded this library for implementing before coming here but do you have any code example to implement it for simple php or codeigniter? I already read the documentation before but not able to understand how to implement this.